# Launch a swing application by using an eclipse plugin button

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, button, plugins

I am currently trying to integrate a Swing application as an Eclipse plugin.
I have in my workspace two separate projects : 
- MyApplication 
- MyPlugin

To launch my application I just need to call  com.[...].Desktop.instance(); from Desktop.java in MyApplication, when I click on the button.
I just want it to launch first so it's really basic.

Here's my code :

```
public void run(IAction action) {

com.[...].Desktop.instance();

}
```

And here's the error I get :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-03-21 12:33:18.862
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/.../Desktop
at boutton_test.actions.SampleAction.run(SampleAction.java:44)
...
```

On my plugin project "properties" -> "Java Build Path" -> "Projects" MyApplication is well added, so I don't really understand why I get such an error.

I also tried something like this :

```
try {
Process MyApplication = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Desktop.java");
MyApplication.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I click on the button nothing happens, and I get nothing in the logs.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Running a Swing application in the same JVM as Eclipse (which is SWT) is difficult and really requires you to use the `SWT_AWT` bridge class.

Comment: @greg-449 ok thank you, I'll look solutions around the bridge class, and update this post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I found was to create a new plug-in from existing JAR Archives called MyApplicationplug, using the .jar from MyApplication.

Then in MyPlugin add it to dependencies, Manifest.MF -> Dependencies -> Add... -> MyApplicationplug

Somehow it worked without conflicts with the JVM.